# What is the difference between `kur test` and `kur evaluate`

Tags: deep-learning

What exactly do `kur test` and `kur evaluate` differ?

The differences we see from console

```
    (dlnd-tf-lab)  ->kur evaluate mnist.yml
    Evaluating: 100%|████████████████████████████| 10000/10000 [00:04<00:00, 2417.95samples/s]
    LABEL     CORRECT   TOTAL     ACCURACY
    0         949       980        96.8%
    1         1096      1135       96.6%
    2         861       1032       83.4%
    3         868       1010       85.9%
    4         929       982        94.6%
    5         761       892        85.3%
    6         849       958        88.6%
    7         935       1028       91.0%
    8         828       974        85.0%
    9         859       1009       85.1%
    ALL       8935      10000      89.3%


    Focus on one: /Users/Natsume/Downloads/kur/examples
    (dlnd-tf-lab)  ->kur test  mnist.yml
    Testing, loss=0.458: 100%|█████████████████████| 3200/3200 [00:01<00:00, 2427.42samples/s]
```

Without understanding the source codes behind `kur test` and `kur evaluate`, how can we understand what exactly do they differ?

Answer (score 0):

@ajsyp the developer of [Kur](https://github.com/deepgram/kur) (deep learning library) provided the following answer, which I found to be very helpful.

> `kur test` is used when you know what the "correct answer" is, and you
>   simply want to see how well your model performs on a held-out sample.
>
> `kur evaluate` is pure inference: it is for generating results from
>   your trained model.
>
> Typically in machine learning you split your available data into 3
>   sets: training, validation, and testing (people sometimes call these
>   different things, just so you're aware). For a particular model
>   architecture / selection of model hyperparameters, you train on the
>   training set, and use the validation set to measure how well the model
>   performs (is it learning correctly? is it overtraining? etc). But you
>   usually want to compare many different model hyperparameters: maybe
>   you tweak the number of layers, or their size, for example.
>
> So how do you select the "best" model? The most naive thing to do is
>   to pick the model with the lowest validation loss. But then you run
>   the risk of optimizing/tweaking your model to work well on the
>   validation set.
>
> So the test set comes into play: you use the test set as a very final,
>   end of the day, test of how well each of your models is performing.
>   It's very important to hide that test set for as long as possible,
>   otherwise you have no impartial way of knowing how good your model is
>   or how it might compare to other models.
>
> `kur test` is intended to be used to run a test set through the model
>   to calculate loss (and run any applicable hooks).
>
> But now let's say you have a trained model, say an image recognition
>   model, and now you want to actually use it! You get some new data (you
>   probably don't even have "truth" labels for them, just the raw
>   images), and you want the model to classify the images. That's what
>   `kur evaluate` is for: it takes a trained model and uses it "in
>   production mode," where you don't have/need truth values.